# Compiling lextex example

Tags: compiling, tex-core, plain-tex

I am trying to use the [`lextex` macros](https://ctan.org/pkg/lextex). For this, I started by taking a look at the example file. I tried to follow the instructions and run

```
tex &plain example1.tex
```

but this gives the message

```
bash: plain: command not found...
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=tex)
**
```

How can I compile the example file for lextex?

Comment: just `tex` will give you plain tex, you don't need `tex&plain` but if you do use it on a bash shell you need `\&` not `&`

Comment: `tex` without `&plain` worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `tex` will give you plain tex, you don't need `tex &plain` but if you do use it on a bash shell you need `\&` not `&`  as `&` ends the command, running tex in the background then tries and fails to run a command `plain`.

Note that this is just general bash syntax, not related to tex or the particular macro file.